# Laravel Selection Query with left join

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

Table - tbl_user_details

```
UserId  | Username
------------------
1       |  jijo
2       |  libin
```

Table  - tbl_user_followups

```
FollowupId  |  UserId  |  Status
---------------------------------
1           |  1       |  Negative
2           |  1       |  Neutral
3           |  1       |  Positive
```

My Controller is

```
$result= DB::table('tbl_user_details')
                        ->leftjoin('tbl_user_followups','tbl_user_details.UserId','=','tbl_user_followups.UserId')
                        ->select('tbl_user_details.*','tbl_user_followups.*')

                        ->orderBy('tbl_user_followups.FollowupId','DESC')
                        ->groupBy('tbl_user_details.UserId')
                        ->get();
```

**I want to get the output like as below**

```
UserId  | Username | FollowupId  |  Status
----------------------------------------
1       |  jijo    |    3        |  Positive
2       |  libin
```

**Anyone can you please suggest an edit in my controller ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood question right: You want list of users with last "followup"? If it is so, then:

```
SELECT d.userid,
       d.username,
       det.followupid,
       det.status
FROM   tbl_user_details d
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid,
                         followupid,
                         status
                  FROM   tbl_user_followups f
                  WHERE  followupid IN (SELECT Max(followupid)
                                        FROM   tbl_user_followups
                                        GROUP  BY userid)) det
              ON d.userid = det.userid
ORDER  BY det.followupid DESC;


 order by det.followupid desc;
```

Please note that "order by det.followupid" will  not  sort them correctly, as we expect for some users to have "null" followupid.

Comment: its working, but I got only one row left join is not working

Comment: its shows both rows:      +--------+----------+------------+----------+
| userid | username | followupid | status   |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+
|      1 | jijo     |          3 | Positive |
|      2 | libin    |       NULL | NULL     |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)